# Errors in very simple fortran program

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I am a fortran beginner and writing a very simple program, compiler GNU fortran.

```
program t1
implicit none
real :: a, b
a=35.4
CHARACTER (LEN=*) :: str = 'This is a test program'
REAL, PARAMETER :: pi = 3.14
WRITE (*,*) a
WRITE (*,*) str
WRITE (*,*) pi
end program
```

I got error `Error: Unexpected data declaration statement` at line 3

`Error: Symbol 'a' has no IMPLICIT type` line 4 and similar for line 8. I am not getting what is going wrong here. Can someone comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran has a strict order. First you declare your data, variables, types, interfaces and then you have your executable code, you cannot mix it. Use the order:

```
program t1

  implicit none

  real :: a, b
  CHARACTER (LEN=*), parameter :: str = 'This is a test program'
  REAL, PARAMETER :: pi = 3.14

  a=35.4

  WRITE (*,*) a
  WRITE (*,*) str
  WRITE (*,*) pi
end program
```

Comment: Getting error at `CHARACTER (LEN=*) :: str = 'This is a test program'`    `Error: Entity with assumed character length at (1) must be a dummy argument or a PARAMETER` Can you tell how to resolve it?

Comment: Yes, just use a fixed length `(len=100)` or add there the `parameter` attribute. I somehow thought you have the `parameter` there, but did not study it well enough..

Comment: I did not get you properly. Are you saying like this `CHARACTER, PARAMETER :: str = 'This is a test program'`  ? This is an error too.

Comment: No, that would be a single character, just 'T', the rest would be ignored. It is actually corrected in my answer.